# Bubble sort refuses to run in application compilers, but runs on online compilers

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

So this is the code I wrote for bubble sorting a user defined list. It crashes (brings the error, 'main.exe has stopped working') when I use apps like DevC++, CodeBlocks and VSCode to run. but when I use a web compiler, it works perfectly.
(The apps only crash while running this code. They are able to run other pieces of code smoothly)

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int numbers[n];
    cout << "How many numbers do you want to sort?\n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the "<< n <<" values.\n";
    for (int w = 0; w < n; w++)
    {
        cin >> numbers[w];
    }

    cout << "The unsorted list is: \n";
    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
        cout << numbers[m] << "\t";
    }
    for (int iterat = 0; iterat < n-1; iterat++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                    numbers[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    cout << "The sorted list is: \n";
    for (int p = 0; p < n; p++)
    {
        cout << numbers[p] << "\t";
    }

}
```

I'm a student and we're currently learning sorting algorithms so I've asked my lecturer and multiple classmates for their help, but they're all stumped on what the problem could be because this should be correct.
Please advice me on what be the problem might be and how to fix it.

Comment: `int numbers[n]` is not valid c++, even if it was `n` is uninitialised

Comment: @AlanBirtles omg, you were right, I just needed to declare the array after n is initialised, thank you so much. It works now

Comment: yes, and use `std::vector` instead of arrays if you want a variable size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is numbers[n] with un initialised value of n. It takes some garbage value of n and  tries to allocate space. It may work sometime and may fail sometime depending on what is the garbage value its taking.

If the garbage value of n is negative or too large, it will fail. Move array declaration after initialisation of n.

Comment: It’s worse than “takes some garbage value”. It’s undefined behavior. It could take some garbage value or it could launch the missiles. turn all your warnings on and the compiler will point out the problem for you. Also, variable-sizes C arrays aren’t standard C++. Use `std::vector<int> numbers;` for this.